# bugzilla with apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, bugzilla

I have a problem with the bugzilla and restarting apache2. When i try to reload apache2 it says:

**The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything. Output of config test was: AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla.conf: DocumentRoot must be a directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.**

The file configuration for bugzilla is: 
ServerName www.bugzilla.sphinx.al 
ServerAdmin elio.pashaj@sphinx.al 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi Options +ExecCGI DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html

Can u help me with Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites enabled/bugzilla.conf: DocumentRoot must be a directory

Comment: The meaning of the error is quite obvious. What did you do to investigate it?

Comment: i don't know how to change from document to a directory. I am new to ubuntu so i don't have enough skills in this field. I searched through the forums and i could'n do it. Can u help me?

Comment: That shouldn't be a document in the first place. Did you even install the Bugzilla correctly?

Comment: Yes i installed it correctly, it was working normally after i installed then i made some configuration on apache2 trying to install frepbx and apache couldn't reload

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that DocumentRoot must be a directory. DocumentRoot in your config is "/var/www/html/bugzilla". Does that path exist? Is it a file or a directory? If you have installed Bugzilla directly in /var/www/html, then /var/www/html/bugzilla will not exist.

If this is a new installation, you would do well to install 5.0 following the instructions here: http://bugzilla.readthedocs.org/en/5.0/ .